# Interecept a method and modify the original parameters

Tags: jakarta-ee

I want to intercept (@AroundInvoke) a method call ... get the original method parameters (pass by reference) with
ctx.getParameters() and replace them with others.. but I want the original parameters to be also modified (!), not just call the method with the new parameters.

Comment: I don't understand... if the parameters are passed by reference when you change them and then call context.proceed() the changed ones will also end up in your @Interceptor annotated bean... Can you please clarify

Answer (score 0):

I'd maybe try subclassing the class that has the method being called, and then modify the parameters before calling super.AroundInvoke(...), like

```
public class AroundInvokerOverrider extends ClassWithAroundInvokeMethod
{
    @override
    public void AroundInvoke(int a, char c, ...)
    {
        a += 1;
        c = 'A';

        super.AroundInvoke(a,c);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't modify the original arguments (which in your case are passed by value which means a copy of them is passed..which is not right). Just calls the method with modified arguments. What I want is afater the interception finishes the original arguments are changed!

Comment: I don't think you can accomplish this (without some haxoring and circumventing anyway) b/c java doesn't support "pass by reference" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference